# PhoneGap Ionic build fails (q.js:126 error) but standard PhoneGap works fine

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

PhoneGap is working for me without any problems, but when i wanted to use Ionic Framework i tried to build project i created i got the following error:

```
c:\Users\Mladen\ionictest\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
...
[error] c:\Users\Mladen\ionictest\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I have read somewhere that latest ionic version requires Node.js v0.11.13 (unstable) so i upgraded it, but that didn't help. I've tried to look for some Ionic framework requirements but found none.

What could be the reason for Ionic project not building but default PhoneGap projects working fine?

Comment: To answer my question: ANDROID_HOME environment variable requires semicolon at the end.